# Cannot perform Union on Custom Entities

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have entities as under

```
public class A
    {
        public string TestMethodName { get; set; }
        public string FailedFor { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public string TestMethodName { get; set; }
        public string FailedFor { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using a windows form. If I try to perform a Union as under

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<A> aCollection = new List<A>();
            List<B> bCollection = new List<B>();

            aCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method1", FailedFor = "DPLServerURL" });
            aCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method2", FailedFor = "DPLServerURL" });
            aCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method3", FailedFor = "DPLServerURL" });
            aCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method4", FailedFor = "DPLServerURL" });


            bCollection.Add(new B { TestMethodName = "Method1", FailedFor = "OrderXmlLocation" });
            bCollection.Add(new B { TestMethodName = "Method2", FailedFor = "OrderXmlLocation" });
            bCollection.Add(new B { TestMethodName = "Method5", FailedFor = "OrderXmlLocation" });

            var xx = bCollection.Union(aCollection).ToList();

        }
```

I am getting error as udner

```
Error   1   Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<WindowsFormsApplication1.B>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<WindowsFormsApplication1.A>'
```

How can I do union/merging of these entities?

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected type of `xx`?

Comment: xx should be the union of aCollection and bCollection.

Comment: aCollection and bCollection are different types

Comment: so in that xcase do u mean that i need to manually iterate thru and put into a seperate coolection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
bCollection.Union(aCollection)
```

with

```
bCollection.Union<object>(aCollection)
```

This creates an `IEnumerable<object>` with each item from the two sources in it. You can't do anything cleverer because, despite having the same properties, there is no kind of link between your classes `A` and `B`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<I> aCollection = new List<I>();
    List<I> bCollection = new List<I>();

    aCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method1", FailedFor = "DPLServerURL" });
    aCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method2", FailedFor = "DPLServerURL" });
    aCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method3", FailedFor = "DPLServerURL" });
    aCollection.Add(new A { TestMethodName = "Method4", FailedFor = "DPLServerURL" });


    bCollection.Add(new B { TestMethodName = "Method1", FailedFor = "OrderXmlLocation" });
    bCollection.Add(new B { TestMethodName = "Method2", FailedFor = "OrderXmlLocation" });
    bCollection.Add(new B { TestMethodName = "Method5", FailedFor = "OrderXmlLocation" });

    var xx = bCollection.Union(aCollection).ToList();
}

public class A : I
{
    public string TestMethodName { get; set; }
    public string FailedFor { get; set; }
}

public class B : I
{
    public string TestMethodName { get; set; }
    public string FailedFor { get; set; }
}

public interface I
{
    string TestMethodName { get; set; }
    string FailedFor { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As alluded to in other answers, since `A` and `B` are different types you can't *directly* create a collection with both types, despite the classes having the same properties.  You have several options:

1. Create a collection of an *anonymous type* that has the same properties as `A` and `B`
2. Create a *base type*/_interface_) that A and B inherit from/implement
3. Create a collection of the *current* base type between `A` and `B` (`object`)

Options 1 and 2 give you the benefit of being able to access the properties of the collection type without casting, while option 3 requires that you cast the items to another class to make them useful.

One question is - why do you have two types that seem to do *exactly the same thing*?